# How to add next & prev buttons with table in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a table where data is inserted from a JSON. Using React.Component, the table creation is below:

```
<tbody>
  {DATA.map(x => (
    <tr>
    <td>{x.date}</td>
    <td>{x.name}</td>
    <td>{x.language}</td>
    <td><a href={x.link} target="_blank" class="btn">Click to Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Data displaying properly but I have to add next & prev buttons with the table. How can I do that?

At least 5 `<tr>` should display simultaneously.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: I do not understand your question : do you mean adding pagination ?

Comment: not pagination just next and previous buttons like pagination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you show so little code, i assume you are using react, and using functional component.

```
const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0); //create page state

const pageData = useMemo(() => { //use useMemo to memorize the page

     return DATA.slice(page*5, (page*5)+5)
},[page])

const nextPage = () => setPage(prev => prev+1) //next page
const prevPage = () => setPage(prev => prev > 0 ? prev-1 : prev) //prev page - need to add condition here so it doesn't go below 0
```

[Reference to Slice method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

in your rendering, use `pageData` instead of `DATA`, example

```
<tbody>
  {pageData.map(x =>
    <tr>
      <td>{x.date}</td>
      <td>{x.name}</td>
      <td>{x.language}</td>
      <td><a href={x.link} target="_blank" class="btn">Click to Listen</a></td>
    </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

You may then create buttons to call `nextPage` and `prevPage` e.g.

```
<button onClick={nextPage}>Next</button>
```

You have to add your own codes to check for maximum number of pages, and minimum number of pages so it doesn't throw error.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-pine-dbbkh?file=/src/App.js:381-418)

Comment: Just add the key property for each element to your newdata.map ...

Comment: poster should know.

Comment: yes sure....but you should know also, and since you did not procided it in your answer, your answer could potentially leads to bugs, which could cause problems for other peoples (i.e the answer is not only for the poster but also for everyone who reads it)

Comment: Question is about next/prev button. Correcting the code is a bonus but not a necessity. If we need to correct the codes then you need to also add codes to show how to generate a non-dynamic uid to be used as key? Then it will lead to backend? Then you need to show how to design the database so each data have unique key? It will become endless. Just saying.

Comment: Also, react by default uses index as key, so asking to add codes to use key={index} is also not necessary

Comment: Yes, but you could also just point out this problem in your answer and loop with the index as a key (even if this is not the best practice). This is just a suggestion man....do as you wish.
I would not be happy if I were a newbie to learn from buggy codes posted as answer.

Comment: React throws warnings/errors pretty well. This is not a question to learn about .map. By the time you reached here, you would have seen warnings from React. And from the questions, are you able to find anything unique to use enough as key?

Comment: I attached error screenshot at the last of my question...

Comment: there's a missing bracket. updated the codes and codesandbox.

Comment: how can i use 'newData' instead of 'Data' actually from 'Data' i'm fetching data from JSON file...

Comment: I mean pageData. pageData is derived from the useMemo returned value. Did you read the codes? It's actually breaking up your Data from JSON file into smaller arrays

Comment: @Someone Special thank you so much this is working fine now...